# Shortest path for a series of points

Tags: shortest-path, transit

I have a points layer with bus stop locations and a line layer which represents the road network. I want to find the shortest path for each bus route based on the sequence of bus stops and save the path as a new layer or extract the paths into a csv file.

I have ensured that the bus stops fall exactly on the road network.

How do I do this in QGIS?