# Creating multiple routes with several stops using QGIS

Tags: qgis, routing, route, shortest-path, points-to-line

I am trying to find the shortest paths given a number of points with a specific order for each path. Specifically, my point data have the following format:

[image]

I used the approved solution given in [Routing with several stops using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380123/routing-with-several-stops-using-qgis), and it works perfectly if my data have only 1 route.

How can I modify the proposed script for making it work for several routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this script: ([Reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380955/29431))

```py
# CHANGE LAYER NAMES
networkLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('networkLayerName')[0]
pointLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('pointLayerName')[0]

output_folder = "/path/to/a/folder" # ADD A FOLDER PATH

route_field_index = pointLayer.fields().indexFromName('route')
unique_routes = pointLayer.uniqueValues(route_field_index)

for unique_route in unique_routes:

    pointLayer.selectByExpression(f"route='{unique_route}'")

    stops = []
    for feat in pointLayer.selectedFeatures():
        stops.append((feat['stop'], feat.geometry().asPoint()))

    #sort by order column
    stops.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    paths = []
    for i, (order, point) in enumerate(stops[0:-1]):
        endPoint = stops[i + 1][1]
        parameters = {'INPUT': networkLayer,
                      'STRATEGY': 0,
                      'DIRECTION_FIELD': '',
                      'VALUE_FORWARD': '',
                      'VALUE_BACKWARD': '',
                      'VALUE_BOTH': '',
                      'DEFAULT_DIRECTION': 2,
                      'SPEED_FIELD': '',
                      'DEFAULT_SPEED': 50.0,
                      'TOLERANCE': 20.0,
                      'START_POINT': point,
                      'END_POINT': endPoint,
                      'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}

        path = processing.run('qgis:shortestpathpointtopoint', parameters)['OUTPUT']
        paths.append(path)    
    
    output = f'{output_folder}/{unique_route}.shp'
    pathsMerged = processing.run('qgis:mergevectorlayers',
                                 {'LAYERS': paths,
                                  'OUTPUT': output})['OUTPUT']
                                  
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(pathsMerged, str(unique_route), 'ogr')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

[image]

I didn't merge the route layers. You may need to merge them.

Comment: Thank you a lot! However I am getting that error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
NameError: name 'stop_field_index' is not defined

Comment: My mistake. Change `stop_field_index` to `route_field_index `.

Comment: Now I am getting that error during the first time:

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 32, in <module>

Comment: File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 105, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 139, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Incorrect parameter value for START_POINT

Comment: I don't know why, but it works at the second run.

Comment: I will check now!

Comment: Yes indeed it doesnt work with the first time. It works with the second. I tried with my original dataset (20 routes) and it takes time. When I tried with 2 routes it took reasonable time to run. Also I have one last question. In my dataset the stop sequence can be like eg 2>15>7>1>20. Therefore, the sequence is not ascending. Maybe I can try to create another column called "order" so it clearly defines the order of the stops!

Comment: Yes, You need to provide an order to the script. Otherwise, it cannot know the order. The order have to be sortable by the script. 2>15>7>1>20 is not sortable.

Comment: I would like to ask you how I can modify the code you provided so I can have an attribute entitled "route" and its value to be the corresponding route number. This will help me a lot with the colouring of the routes based on unique attribute. Thanks! @Kadir Şahbaz